# Kill a database query after command outputs a pattern

Tags: bash

I have the following command that downloads a file from a database, then checks its integrity and exits:

```
cmd_db -get file_1
```

ouput:

```
Getting file_1
Transferring data (10% done)
Transferring data (20% done)
...
Transferring data (90% done)
Transferring data (100% done)
Getting MD5
ERROR: stream broke
Exiting...
```

The file downloads properly but is erased after the error occurs.
I managed to manually kill the command when the output reaches "100% done".
After checking the MD5 manually, the file is actually fine.
There is something wrong with my connection and I already spent days trying to figure it out. So far the manual killing is the only solution that works.

So, I am trying to automate the killing but none of the following commands work. The program actually stops producing an output when it reaches "100% done", but continues until the end and erases the file.

```
cmd_db -get file_1 | sed '/100% done/q'
cmd_db -get file_1 | while read line; do test "$line" = "100% done" && killall; done
until cmd_db -get file_1 | grep -m 1 "100% done"; do : ; done
```

Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, since I don't know what your command is, I'll have to work around it.  First, redirect the output of the command to `grep`, which will will look for the '100% done' and put that in a file.  Put the whole thing in the background:

```
cmd_db -get file_1 | grep '100% done' > tmp$$ &
```

You are going to need that process ID, so that we can kill it later:

```
child=$!
```

Now, that file is going to be empty until we get that string.  Put yourself into an infinite loop, and test the file size until it's greater than zero, then kill the child process and break out of the loop:

```
while true; do
  [ $( wc -c tmp$$ | cut -d' ' -f1 ) -gt 0 ] && { kill -9 $child; break; }
done
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks ! Unfortunately, still the same problem. The command for downloading file is a database proprietary java client

Comment: That post-download step is probably happening so fast you won't be able to stop it.  Do you have the java code?